# Bitmaps from URL into listview

Tags: android, url, listview, bitmap

I first make an async task to retrieve JSON data. One of the JSON objects retrieved is an URL.

```
// This goes on my asynctask to get JSON data from the server
@Override
public void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
  try {
    String title = json.getString("title");
    String description = json.getString("description");
    String url = json.getString("url");

    // Here comes the tricky part
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100,100,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    new DownloadBitmap(bitmap).execute(url);
    myArrayList.add(new DataContainer(title,description,bitmap));
    // End of the tricky part




  }catch(Exception e) {}
   adapter.NotifyDataSetChange();
}
```

OK as you can see I need a reference of `bitmap` to send to the downloader class and to the arraylist for the listview's adapter.

The problem is that the downloader class goes like this:

```
class DownloadBitmap extends AsyncTask<the 3 paramateres goes here>{

  Bitmap bitmap;

  public DownloadBitmap(Bitmap b) {

    //Here I have a reference to the SAME bitmap object I added to the arraylist
    bitmap = b;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doInBackground(String... Params) {
    // some code.....

    // THIS IS THE PROBLEM, it re-initialize.
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputstream);
  }
```

I wasn't able to find any other way around, and If possible I'd like a solution library independant, my company has strict policy over software dependance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Universal Image Loader Library.
[link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: If possible I'd like a solution library independant, my company has strict policy over software dependance. Thanks

Comment: you can use lazy loading list and you can include its classes and modify it according your needs.